# RecyclerView places a horrible space between each element

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

Hi how do you do? Can someone help me?

I want to display a RecyclerView and have the items display one after the other.

But I do not understand why a horrible space is shown between each of the elements in a horrible way as you can see in this image.

[image: phone screenshot trouble]

I want to show all the elements of the recycler view without the white space.

Here are my **xml** that I use

**cardview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<View
    android:id="@+id/gradient"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/vertical_gradient_up"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideLine2"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="México"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/place_holder"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:srcCompat="@color/white"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/brand_news"
    style="@style/App"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="BRAND NEWS"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideLine2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/brand_news"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/body"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/body"
    style="@style/App"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/date"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="Subtitle
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    style="@style/App"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/body"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="Fecha de la noticia"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    />



<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@id/guideLine2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7"
    />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideLine3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

**activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/contentView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".SectionFeed.ExperiencesFeed"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/loaderMask"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.6"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loaderImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:scaleX="0.7"
            android:scaleY="0.7" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/hedaer"
            style="@style/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/headerSize"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <include
                layout="@layout/static_header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/followHeader"
            style="@style/headerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_header"
            android:background="@drawable/view_underlined_black"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hedaer"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/surveyTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/encuestas_titulo"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_font_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                style="generalPaddingStart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingStart="20dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2px"
                    android:background="@color/black" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pushNotification"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/title_header"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/followHeader"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            >

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewExperiencesFeed"
            tools:listitem="@layout/cardview_experience_general_feed"
            tools:itemCount="5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pushNotification"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/assistFooter"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minHeight="300dp"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/assistFooter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/footerSize"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerViewExperiencesFeed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/footer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/footerSize"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <include
                    layout="@layout/static_footer_contact_btn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftMenu"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                layout="@layout/menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

***I appreciate any advice or suggestion***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar issue, with `RelativeLayout` as the root element for each row in the `recyclerview`. I will suggest changing the view layout to `RelativeLayout`.

To solve the issue, find the XML file that holds each row and make sure that the root element's height is `wrap_content` NOT match_parent.

Comment: Thank you very much mate, this solution helped me a lot, I also did not know that the backend images came corrupt and they show that ugly, now backend has to solve that, I spent so much time for something that was not my fault, I will quit soon, I promise .

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error 1 year ago.
Try changing the `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: I already answered the same solution why you are coping giving the same answer?

Comment: Sorry bro, I did not see your answer.
After posting the answer, you will see it.

Comment: Thank you very much bro, this solution helped me a lot.